# does anyone know what visual assist is?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-assist

Can anyone please tell me what is the main use of visual assist? Does it really help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a plugin for Visual Studio that gives you better code completion and other productivity features (e.g. code refactoring and better find/replacing).  I find VS unusable without it so I would really recommend it.

http://www.wholetomato.com/

Answer (score 2):

As TheJuice said. However, bare in mind that the usefulness of it depends on your programming language. I use it heavily when I'm writing C++ code. If I'm writing C# code, Resharper is my tool of choice.

Comment: @sean - oops, yes I did! That's what I get for doing 5 million things at the same time ;-)